# Hardware issue, bsod with windows xp irq and strange messages with ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, hardware-failure, ubuntu-12.04

I have an old [Acer T160](http://www.topproduct.nl/hardware/desktopcomputers/13034-acer/137699-acer-aspire-t160/267384-acer-aspire-t160-amd-sempron-3200-92.nib62.hg3.html) and it used to run Windows XP. But I keep getting random BSOD's. I keep seeing IRQ conflicts. I tried to run ubuntu, which runs and keeps running. But sometimes is not responding. Also there are these popups at ubuntu 12.04 that my network cable (which is onboard) is unplugged. But I have no cable in it! and have an usb dongle for wifi. which also seems unstable. have to (auto)reconnect sometimes.

So my question is: **is it my mobo, power supply or something else?**

FYI: I had an dvd-rw station which did not open properly, so unplugged the ata and power, als removed the second harddrive. now only have sata harddrive. also removed the extra video card (ati sapphire x1600 pro) so use only onboard video now and still have these issues.

**EDIT** Update: will try with a new PSU (power supply unit of 400watt) the old (factory) one was 300watt. and will use a usb drive which has 12.04 ubuntu on it (made with wubi) to format everything and re-install ubuntu. (so also delete mbr partition) will update the day after tomorrow.

**EDIT 2** I have checked the case for dust and vacuum cleaned it. But that did not change a bit. It still seems that the motherboard is failing. because of the losing network connection (which has no cable in it) and the randomly dropping wifi (usb dongle) and the randomly not responsive usb mouse.

**EDIT 3** I have inserted a new psu and still have random wifi dropping (which is a pci add on card) the dvd drive is somehow only opened by using an iron strip and some force. but it works. installed ubuntu 12.04 from CD and runs faster/better.

**EDIT 4** I have run [pc check 6 from eurosoft](http://www.eurosoft-uk.com/pccheck.html) and it have not found any motherboard issues. still have random dropping of the onboard lan or pci wifi and the dvd drive will not open normally. **Can this be a bootsectorvirus?** because pc check said I have one.

Answer (score 0):

This very much sounds unfortunately like a motherboard problem. Before losing all hope you can check to see if it is just a MBR error. More information is given [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) on that.

It is also possible that this is the result of a virus that attempts to infect the Master Boot Record or boot sector. If the fixmbr command does not work, please try formatting your drive with a Windows installation CD that you boot into. Select custom installation and then proceed to the partitioning options. Once there, try deleting all partitions and re-making them with the "new" button in the partitioning window.

Also, I would try moving the computer to an area with good ventilation and also try popping it open and cleaning it out a bit, as very dusty components can also cause these issues.

Comment: Ok, will try to vacuum the machine. I was able to install ubuntu with wubi. dvd drive will not open...

Comment: Is it only not opening when you push the button? Or are you able to stick a paper clip into the small hole on the front side of it (Normally directly under the tray) and manually open it? Because if you can't open it like that then you have got a jammed tray...

Comment: When I push the button the light blinks and it makes noise but the tray does not come out. Had to use some force and a strip of metal to get my dvd out. that's why it is not connected anymore. thought that that drive caused the issues

Comment: Yes well, if all else fails you may want to attempt the format I outlined in my answer. I too have had that problem with my DVD drive. Only it's on the fritz, not completely ruined lol. Not yet at least...

Comment: No virus, because i removed all partitions. no psu issue, because i inserted a new psu. no dust issue, because there was only a little and vacuum cleaned it.

Comment: Well then I believe it's an issue with your motherboard.